# Webfont rendering issue: browsers seem to be confused about size and position

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering, webfonts

I am using two webfonts in a project. One of them has a rendering issue I have never encountered before. The other one works as expected.

Generally, the problem seems to be that the browser has a hard time determining the size and position of the text.

**In Safari, I notice:**

- When selecting text, the selection box renders higher than the text is rendered.
- When clicking a link, I have to click higher than the actual text.

**In Chrome, I notice:**

- When selecting text, the selection box renders way larger than the text is rendered.
- When clicking a link, I have to click higher than the actual text.

In Firefox, the issue is the least noticeable. There is no obvious shift in position. The overlay for the text seems a little small / shifted down, though.

Does anybody have any clue as to what is happening here? Why only for this particular font?

---

[image: Trying to select the first line in Safari]
*Selecting the first–not the third–line in Safari*

[image]
*Selecting the first line in Chrome*

[image]
*Selecting the first line in Firefox*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question by contacting the creators of the problematic font. So in case anyone stumbles on this question later...

The odd behavior is caused by a few special characters that extend way beyond the usual bounderies. While I never use these characters, most browsers today seem to determine the line height based on the largest character in the font, not the largest character used.